# Adding dropdown list to columns in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a grid and I want to set a dropdown list with Yes & No for some columns. I am not able to put that dropdown list like I mentioned below. Its because I use checkbox in the grid to edit the rows. So even if I put these I am not able to see the drop down when I click the checkbox to edit.

```html
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Lead" ItemStyle-Width="100">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblLead" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Lead") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLead" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Lead") %>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList id="ddlLead" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="Yes"> Yes </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="No"> No </asp:ListItem> 
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: try to set on databoundevent

Comment: Can you post the entire markup for your GridView?

Comment: Here it is. Pls take a look.

Comment: That does not look like the entire markup for your grid.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected void grdVw_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
          grdVw.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

            /* Insert specific editing logic here */

            grdBind();//method to bind gridview
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you gotta make sure you are setting the mode to Edit. For this I use the default buttons, and you are using checkboxes, they should both work:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <%--Other columns here--%>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then, you need to handle the RowEditing event, by setting the EditIndex to the index of the row you want to edit, and re-bind the GridView:

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    setDataSource(); //this sets the data source of the grid, and re-binds it.
}
```